# Does getrecievedbyaddress work for all addresses?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

In previous versions `getrecievedbyaddress` api call returned 0 for external addresses (not included into local wallet) and it was described in the docs. However, right now documentation for `getrecievedbyaddress` doesn't mention externall/local addresses.

Does this mean that I can use this api call for any address?

Answer (score 2):

No, it only works for wallet addresses. You can add watch-only addresses without key via `importaddress`, though.